# Is there a way to bind a combobox with a Directory at the local disc C:/ or D:/

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop-application, app.xaml

I'm Using WPF in Visual Studio 2017 and I am wandering if there is a way to bind a file source ("C:/example", "*.xml") to a Combobox programmatically.

the idea is to have all the xml files in a Combobox or a List, withoud being obliged to load each time a specific xml file with xDoc.load(path) a 100 times

I tried to get this files into my `Combobox` with `SelectionChanged` Event but it didn't work.

Any idea about how to get my files.

**xaml Event declaration**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SourceFile" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Source"/>
```

**My Essai**

```
private void ComboBox_Source(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\export");
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.xml");
    foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        this.SourceFile.Items.Add(file);

    }
```

Comment: Why making photos, when you can/should post the code. Could you please edit your question and post the code ?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [DriveInfo.GetDrives Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.8) ... please don't post screenshots of your code - post as text here.

Comment: it's WPF right?

Comment: @Avinash Reddy, exactely its WPF

Comment: Selection changed occurs whenever u changed so. add it in ctro and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't add the code but I found a way to my Question.
I used Directory Info to get to the folder in my Local disc then with the FileInfo class of System.IO I get all the files with the extention that I want and Eventually add this files as Items in my CheckBox

[MySolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4kg0.png)